# To find the index of a conditional turn point in list

Tags: python

I have a list and I want to identify the index of the turn point.

Only when the previous 5 data point, or more than that, showing a decrease, is considered as a turn point.

```
da_list = [100,99,98,105,94,78,52,51,49,48,47,50,40,41,39,33,36,22] 
                      ^                    ^        ^
                      not                  is      not
```

With a clumsy way, it tells the index is 10:

```
for idx, each in enumerate(da_list):
    if da_list[idx - 5] > da_list[idx - 4] and \
    da_list[idx - 4] > da_list[idx - 3] and \
    da_list[idx - 3] > da_list[idx - 2] and \
    da_list[idx - 2] > da_list[idx - 1] and \
    da_list[idx - 1] > da_list[idx] and \
    da_list[idx] <= da_list[idx + 1]:
        print (idx, each)
```

What would be a smarter way to do so, especially if the list became longer and it requires 100 decreasing data points?

Comment: why not `48` ? `105,94,78,52,51,49 -->48`

Comment: @Epsi95, after "105,94,78,52,51,49 -->48" is 47, it's still decreasing. It needs to find a turn point where starts to increase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try `groupby` from itertools

```py
from itertools import groupby

da_list = [22,36,33,39,41,40,50,47,48,49,51,52,78,94,105,98,99,100]
diff = list(map(lambda x: 1 if x>=0 else -1 , da_list[0:1] + [e-da_list[i-1] for i,e in enumerate(da_list[1:], 1)]))

carrying_index = -1
for gp_name, grp in groupby(diff):
    length = len(list(grp))
    carrying_index += length
    if(gp_name == -1 and length >= 5):
        print(da_list[carrying_index])
```

another simpler way

```py
from itertools import groupby

da_list = [100,99,98,105,94,78,52,51,49,48,47,50,40,41,39,33,36,22,21,20]
diff = da_list[0:1] + [e-da_list[i-1] for i,e in enumerate(da_list[1:], 1)]


for g_name, grp in groupby(zip(da_list, range(len(da_list)), diff), key=lambda x: x[-1]>=0):
    if not g_name:
        l_group = list(grp)
        if(len(l_group) >= 5):
            print('index: ', l_group[-1][1])
            print('value: ', l_group[-1][0])
            
            
# index:  10
# value:  47
```

Comment: thank you for posting an update. The first method, when the da_list  is changed to [22,36,33,39,41,40,50,47,48,49,51,52,78,94,105,98,99,100], it finds the turn point of continuous upward to downward, which on the opposite of what it should look for (continuous downward to upward).

Comment: @MarkK I forgot to check the only decrementing condition, thanks, updated! `if(gp_name == -1 and length >= 5):`

Comment: superb! thanks for the update. the 2nd method, can you please update it for a way to get the its index too?

Comment: great job! thanks again. wish you a good weekend!

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple yet effective way

```
data = [100,99,98,105,94,78,52,51,49,48,47,50,40,41,39,33,36,22]

num_decreases = 0
old_val = data[0]
turn_points = list()
REQUIRED_DECREASES = 5
for i, d in enumerate(data[1:]):
    if d - old_val < 0:
        num_decreases += 1
    else:
        if num_decreases >= REQUIRED_DECREASES:
            turn_points.append((i, d))
        num_decreases = 0
    old_val = d

print(turn_points)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. It's a good one and the result is a list of tuples. Can I have your understanding that, I choose another answer, which returns' are simpler? Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Sure :) However, just change `turn_points.append((i,d))` into `turn_points.append(i)` if you only care about the index

Comment: I just hope can choose both of yours as answers! wish you a good weekend!